# What are some ORMs similar to Active Record that can be used for a php Implementation for MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, activerecord, orm, nosql

Hey everyone. I'm looking for a good Active-Record like data abstraction layer to hook into MongoDB for my PHP based website. Currently, I'm developing on Zend Framework, if that makes a difference. Can you give me a good suggestion?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine has a (beta) [MongoDB Object Document Mapper](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb_odm). Havne't tried it yet, but I think it does what you are asking for.

Comment: I set up Doctrine with Mongo and then Zend. It worked like a charm. Thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: If you liked his solution, then mark his answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Mandango](http://mandango.org/) is another Mongo ODM you might want to try out. According to [this page](http://mandango.org/performance) on the Mandango site, it's faster than Doctrine's Mongo ODM.

(disclosure: I used to work with Mandango's lead developer)